# Referencing PHP arrays returned from MySQL for a JSON API

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, api

I have a result, `$result`, returned from an SQL query which contains the following data: `[{"TOTAL":"12345"}]`

I want to put that result into a JSON API with a route of, say, `/api/total/` and have it return: `{total:12345}`. I'll be setting the first half of that manually, e.g. `'total' => whatever` in the Slim framework.

```
$app->render(200, array(
    'total' => $result["TOTAL"]
    )
);
```

How do I reference `12345` from the returned array? Doing `$result["TOTAL"]` doesn't work.

Comment: use json_decode($result)

Comment: Its json so decode it then use $result["TOTAL"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result looks like `[{"TOTAL":"12345"}]`?

So you have to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first.

```
$decodedResult = json_decode($result, true);
echo $decodedResult[0]['TOTAL'];
```

Comment: WARNING: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 1):

Use this code , you will get the value.

```
    $result = '[{"TOTAL":"12345"}]';
    $res = json_decode($result);
    echo $res[0]->TOTAL;
```

Comment: I receive: WARNING: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: have you copied the same code?? or have you changed anything?? Because, that's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Please try this
```

```
$res = json_decode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

even though there is only one object in the array, it is still an array so you need to reference the object's index.

```
$result[0]["TOTAL"]
```